# Hide text box based on parameter values

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hope someone can help as I am quite new to SSRS, I am trying to hide a text box that has an expression in it. When multiple values from a drop down parameter are selected I want to hide the box but when only one option is selected I want to show just the one option.

I currently have a text box with the following expression in it

=First(Fields!Name.Value, "ABC")

The above currently shows the first Value from a field which is correct, but when as I said there are more values selected, I want to hide this, I am not sure if I need to wrap the above expression in something or change this in the Text Box properties under visibility

I have been trying to add the following expression under the Text Box Properties/Visibility option, but not having much luck

=Iif(Parameters!Supplier.IsMultiValue > 1, True, False)

I am using SSRS 2012 though I am sure what I am trying to do is quite easily done in every other version.

Hope someone can help, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a multi value parameter is an array, you need to use a formula like this:

```
=Iif(Parameters!Supplier.Value.Length > 1, True, False)
```

or as suggested by the OP

```
=Iif(Parameters!Supplier.Count > 1, True, False)
```

Comment: Hi Joao,  thanks for the quick response I have tried your suggestion but I am geting the following error message :- "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the text box 'Textbox6' contains an error: [BC30456] 'Length' is not a member of 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Parameter'.  Not really sure what that means?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. you need the Value in there

Comment: Hi Joao, not sure what you meant by needing the value but after your suggestion I have done the following and it seems to be working, unless you can see any drawback with this  =Iif(Parameters!Supplier.Count > 1, True, False) what are your thoughts as I am trying to learn as much about SSRS as possible, thanks again for the help.

Comment: There's no drawback, essentially is the same thing. By using the `Value` property you get the array of selected parameters.